# Jquery popup does not updated displaying the old list

Tags: c#, jquery, html, razor, model-view-controller

I am loading a div using the below statement.

```
.load("/Index/ImportCase");
```

The above statement perfectly calls the corresponding Action Method and view page, it holds the updated list in model. But the popup displays the old list.

I refreshed the page, eventhough its not updating my list.
I want my popup to be display the updated list.

The only way i found is to force the application to update the popup is to exit and return into the application.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Try .empty().load("/Index/ImportCase");

Comment: Reporting an error: Try is undefined

Comment: try is not part of code, Lenap is telling you to try `.empty().load("/Index/ImportCase");`

Comment: .empty().append("/Index/OmportCase");

Comment: Sorry didnt read the error :s

Comment: No this is not works for me.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time before loading the content into the div, make sure to clear the old content as:

```
.html("");    // Invoke it on your div
```

Then call load function to populate the content inside div.

Comment: Thank you so much.Its works perfect.Wish to vote and accept this as correct answer.